Ubuntu en un Seagate ST1000LM035-1RK1721 / Ubuntu on a Seagate ST1000LM035-1RK1721
Original question:
Tengo una core I5 7500u, hay benchmarks para ver si Ubuntu va mejor que mi Windows 10 ?, y también veo que mi disco hdd es un Seagate ST1000LM035-1RK1721, Ubuntu será compatible y "mejor o igual" con el disco que tengo a comparación de Windows 10

AI translated question:
I have an Intel Core i5 7500U processor. Are there benchmarks to see if Ubuntu performs better than my Windows 10? Also, I see that my HDD is a Seagate ST1000LM035-1RK1721. Will Ubuntu be compatible and perform 'better or the same' with the disk I have compared to Windows 10?

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, the site is in English and so must be questions and answers that get posted on it; I translated the title and the question using AI to avoid it being closed, please review the translation, see if it fits what you intended to ask and then remove the spanish parts from the title and the question. Thanks!

Your performance will not improve between Windows and Linux on a spinning disk.  That HDD is your performance bottleneck because spinning disk media has much worse response time than SSDs.

This question is similar to: Will my device work with Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
